# Python list appending while incrementing

Tags: python, algorithm, list

How can I increment a list in python.In the following case

So that means
   I want to append several lists into a single list is is easy like list1+list2

But I need to return a final list where all the lists will be appended and every single list will be an result of iteration.What I was trying like below:

```
def result():  
    temps = [list of links]
    final_list = [] 
    for link in temps:
        final_list = final_list+get_list(link) # get list returning a list and temps is a list
    return final_list


 def get_list(link):
        #process the link and return a list
        return li
```

But as every time before the loop,final_list is being initialized,I am getting the `[]+get_list()`
I need all the previous values in my final list.

> Sample input: [a list of links] Sample out put:final_list #contains
>   all the data as a single list returned from get_list()

Comment: Can you give an example of an input and the expected output?

Comment: Could you show an example of what data you have and what you want the final list to be? I've read your question three times, and I still don't see what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: same here..i am not able to get your question after reading it twice... what actually are you trying to ask..??

Comment: still not very clear. can you be more specific? Here's what I _think_ you're saying: You want to join a bunch of lists with items in them (say strings for example)? `l1 = [a, b]` `l2 = [c, d]` `final_list = [a, b, c, d]` ? Is that about right?

Comment: It seems to me that your code already would do what you want. Perhaps the problem is in a part you did not show us.

Comment: Are you calling `result()` more than once? If you are initializing `final_list` outside the loop, then it should be fine right?. Anyway, you can use what strcat suggested for this to make it shorter and pythonic: `result_list = [value for l in temps for value in getlist(l)]`. Just one line!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to turn a list of something into a list of lists and flatten it?

```
>>> strings = ["one two", "three four", "five six"]
>>> [value for s in strings for value in s.split()]
['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six']
```

Comment: don't use `sum( , [])`, use `itertools.chain` or the list comprehension.

Comment: no,simply I want to get a output that is a list,and this list will be originated from other lists like for i in range(0,3):out = get_list() where get_list return a new list every time and out returns all the previous results

Comment: If you provide an example of a real input (in python, not English) and the expected output it would be easier to understand what you want.

Comment: temps = ["link1","link2"] final_list = [] for i in temps: y =final_list+get_data(i) return final_list where get_data returns a list,my problem us when I am doing final_list+get_data(i) it returns something []+returned list from get_data() ,bcoz final_list is initialized as []

Comment: Your code should work. If you don't provide the actual python input/output no one can help you any further. Stop trying to explain like this because you're really not helping.

Answer (score 1):

if you want something like this:

```
get_list(L1) -> ['L1_val1','L1_val2']
get_list(L2) -> ['L2_val1','L2_val2']
result([L1,L2]) -> ['L1_val1','L1_val2','L2_val1','L2_val2'] (a)
```

or

```
result([L1,L2]) -> [['L1_val1','L1_val2'],['L2_val1','L2_val2']] (b)
```

i would suggest:

builtin map:

```
map(get_list,(L1,L2,..)) -> [['L1_val1','L1_val2'],['L2_val1','L2_val2'],..]
```

itertools.chain:

```
chain(*map(get_list,(L1,L2,..))) -> iterator obj # star unpacks tuple into sequens of args
List(chain(*map(get_list,(L1,L2,..)))) -> ['L1_val1','L1_val2','L2_val1','L2_val2',..]
```

So your code could be rewritten as

```
from itertools import chain

def result_a(list_of_links):  
    return List(chain(*map(get_list,list_of_links)))

def result_b(list_of_links):  
    return map(get_list,list_of_links)

def get_list(one_link):
    #process the link and return a list
    return list_of_processed_values
```

Answer (score 0):

All the other answers are way more complex than needed. Instead of:

```
final_list = [] 
for link in temps:
    final_list = final_list+get_list(link)
```

Use:

```
final_list = [] 
for link in temps:
    final_list.extend(get_list(link))
```